# Firebreath plugin detected in firefox but cannot be used in website

Tags: firefox, plugins, firebreath

my firebreath plugin is detected in firefox in the Add-On's-section after registering the dll. But when I request a website which needs that plugin, firefox says that additions plugins are necessary to use the whole content of the website (means somehow not detecting the plugin).

Everything works when using google chrome.

Does anybody know why firefox detects the plugin but does not apply it?

Some useful enviroment and setup information: 
- Win8 64Bit
- Firefox (version 22.0)
- Google Chrome (version 29.0.1547.57 m)
- The plugin was created by running prep2012.cmd (32Bit)

**Edit**

I just embedded the object-tag in my html-file:

`<object id="myPlugin" type="{{'application/x-myBrowserPlugin'}}"></object>`

And in javascript, I get a reference to my plugin via following code. I use AngularJS, so the $document-service retrieves the element with the specified id (similar to `window.document` in normal javascript, it's just a wrapper).

`var plugin = function() 
{
     return $document[0].getElementById('myPlugin);
};`

**Edit**

Just found out, that my plugin cannot be used also in IE 10 (10.0.9200.16660).
There must be something wrong with my plugin.

I registered the plugin with command line and executed 'regsvr32'

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does it show up in about:plugins ?

Comment: check about:plugins page if the plugin is detected successfully. And also post the code for embedding your plugin in the page. Does your plugin require any other dependency dlls?

Comment: Yes, when I enter about:plugins in Firefox, my plugin is shown. My plugin requires another DLL, which is loaded dynamically by invoking an command to the plugin. This works well in Chrome, so I don't think that this is the problem, because event the plugin version cannot be retreived from the plugin.